# How do I use request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') within template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to use `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` within template.

**My template source:**

```
<!-- this is login.html -->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}django bookmark- login{% endblock %}
{% block head %}login{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}
    <p>try again!</p>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
        <p><label for="id_username">username:</label>
        {{ form.username }}</p>
        <p><label for="id_password">password:</label>
        {{ form.password }}</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/<!-- I WANT TO USE 'HTTP_REFERER' HERE -->" />
        <input type="submit" value="login" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

How what should I do?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

Answer (score 16):

There's no need for `get`.`request.META` is a dictionary, and as with all dictionaries, you can perform field lookup in the template using the dot notation: `{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}`

Comment: That means it's empty. In this case because he has a typo, which is understandable given the name is misspelt itself. Try `{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}`; if it's empty, that means there wasn't one.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Python, but one reason for using the .get notation is to specify a default value of no value is present.  E.g.:
request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER", "localhost") would cause it to either return the actual value of HTTP_REFERER or return localhost if there is no HTTP_REFERER.  Not sure if this syntax works in a template, but it might be a reason for choosing one over the other.

Answer (score 6):

Add `django.core.context_processors.request` in your settings file in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` then you would be able to use the `request` in template without explicitly passing it in request `context`.

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.request', # this one
)
```

the in template you could do `{{request.META.HTTP_REFERER}}`

Comment: I can't this answer... What should apply this?? settings.py? But my settings.py have not TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS variable... I using django 1.4.3. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Actually the preferred way is to use the `next` parameter as [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users)

You can do in your template something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{  request.GET.next }}" />
```