# How to get the URL of the page in a CreateView of the Report/Flag User objectUR

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create one report model that will go on all my templates. The idea is that members will be able to report other members for unauthorized content. the moderator will know what is being reported by the URL of the page and the username of the user on that template. I am not sure how to get the URL on which the report button is clicked. I am also having difficulty returning the user to the same page once the report object is created

Below is the model for the **report models.py**

```
class Report(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='reporting_members')
    reported = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='reported_members')
    report_url = models.URLField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    reported_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    reporting_choices = (
        ('1', 'The images posted by this user are not relevant to the Post),
        ('2', 'Rude or abusive content, The words chosen by the user are inappropriate'),
        ('3', 'This user is asking me to change my review in return for favor '),
        ('4', 'Other'),
    )
    reason_to_report = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=reporting_choices)
    explain_reason = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Below are my **views.py**

```
class ReportCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Report
    fields = ('reason_to_report', 'explain_reason')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.reporter = self.request.user  #This works
        form.instance.reported = User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs.get('username')) #This works
        form.instance.report_url = self.kwargs.get()#I am not sure how to get this URL  
        super().form_valid(form)
        return redirect(self.request.META['HTTP_REFERER']) #This line is not working not sure how to get the user back to the same page
```

However if I make the reporting member to copy paste URL in this field instead of trying to get in using code. The object is created. But I need the URL to be got automatically

Below are the URLS.py of the app. Its just 1 url

```
app_name = 'report'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', views.ReportCreateView.as_view(), name='report_user'),

]
```

The URL that is to be reported will look something like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/Amanda/7/  (This is Amanda's Post)          
http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/George/9/ (This is George's Post Amanda has a comment on this Post)
```

The hrefs of the button changes depending on which object the flag button is placed. below are 2 different places the flags buttons are placed

```
<a href="{% url 'report:report_user' username=post.user.username %}"> #If the flag is on the post
<a href="{% url 'report:report_user' username=post.comment.author.username %}"> #If the flag is on the comment
```

Comment: for `form.instance.report_url = ` try `self.request.path` if that works you should be able to use the same path for the redirect?

Comment: @Mint awesome that worked now how do I get the user back to the same page

Comment: @Mint it gives me the URL of the form page. so I guess I need the URL on the page the button was clicked before it came to the form to create report

Comment: can you add the urls.py of the app.

Comment: @Mint just added the urls.py to the question

Comment: ok, where are you redirected to when you remove the the return statement?

Comment: @Mint It gives me a error message 

`ImproperlyConfigured at /report/Amanda/
No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.`  But as long as there is any URL the object is created. But the moderator won't know which post is reported

Comment: @Mint `self.request.path` prints the url `/report/Amanda/` If Amanda was a active user it wont be easy to look for what is being reported

Comment: @Mint self.request.path does not work. It prints the url `/report/Amanda/` If Amanda was a active user it wont be easy to look for what is being reported.  Thank you for the get_absolute_url

Comment: I would want the url that the report button was clicked on. The Post Url I am tinkering with `HTTP_REFERER` to get the previous url

Comment: so you're looking for something like `/Amanda/post/5`? can you add the url of the page that is supposed to be reported.

Comment: Ok sorry, I was misunderstanding. what is the value of `HTTP_REFERER` ?

Comment: @Mint well `/Amanda/post/5` that could be one scenario or `/George/post/6` where Amanda as a comment on that post. If I know which page to look and who is the user. It is easy. Otherwise I have go through all of Amanda's Post and all of Amanda's comments

Comment: @Mint `HTTP_REFERER` not working either gives the same results as `self.request.path
`

Comment: can you also add the url where the report button is.

Comment: @Mint I have added the button urls above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out made changes to the form template thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010177/how-do-i-use-request-meta-gethttp-referer-within-template) and to @Mint who guided me in the right direction

```
<form action="" method="post" >
   {% csrf_token %}
   {% bootstrap_form form %}
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}">#This is where the magic happens. This gets the URL before the form page
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" />            
 </form>
```

Below are the **views.py**

```
class ReportCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Report
    fields = ('reason_to_report', 'reason')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.reporter = self.request.user
        form.instance.reported = User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        next = self.request.POST.get('next') #This keeps the post URL in memory
        form.instance.report_url = next

        super().form_valid(form)
        return redirect(form.instance.report_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# views.py
def form_valid(self, form):
    ...
    form.instance.report_url = self.request.path

# models.py
from django.urls import reverse
class Report(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('report_user', kwargs={'username': self.reported})
```